# PHP: How to get parent abstract class private property from child class with reflections or with another way

Tags: php

I have a situation like this.

#### So we have abstract `father` that have private `$secret` property.

```
abstract class father{
    private $secret = 'my_secret';
}
```

#### And also have a child class

```php
class child extends father{
    public function getFatherSecret(){
        // some code to get a private prop
    }
}
```

> I don't know maybe it's impossible.

So I need to get a parent private property like [Closure binding](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/accessing-private-php-class-members-without-reflection/) method or unserializing method that already fully explained on some PHP documentations.

Comment: Best quote `I should hereby add a disclaimer: use with caution!`.

Comment: Why not just implement `public function getFatherSecret()` in the father class?

Comment: @MarkusZeller because abstract belongs to another vendor.

Comment: The problem is that you are relying on the implementation of a class which you don't have ownership of.  So if that class changes, you code may break without warning.

Comment: I understand the responsibility but unfortunately, even risky methods do not really exist.

Comment: On a more pragmatic note, unless the vendor package was poorly written or you are dealing with an edge case, maybe dig some more for what you actually need, the package might expose some of its stuff (allowing you to configure, log, process etc.) which means you could fiddle with it without hacking access modifiers.

Comment: When father class changes, all your code may break. Better work for such a case with your own config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have all sorts of reservations about the use of this method, there is always the principle of answering a problem (even if it is purely in an academic sense).

So...

```
abstract class father{
    private $secret = 'my_secret';
}

class child extends father{
    public function getFatherSecret(){
        $closure = Closure::bind(function (father $f) { return $f->secret; }, 
            null, "father");

        print_r($closure($this));
    }
}

$c = new child();
$c->getFatherSecret();
```

gives...

```
my_secret
```